# Formatting values

Tags: c#

Hi i have a `int`  example as `3` i need to format it as `003` . is the only way is convert to a `string` and `concat` and convert back ?

Comment: What is showing this formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
int n = 3;
string formatted = n.ToString("000");
```

Alternatively:

```
string formatted = String.Format("{0:000}", n);
```

[More info here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the `.ToString("000");` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Debug.WriteLine(3.ToString("000"));
```

You can parse the resulting string value by using `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`:

```
Debug.WriteLine(int.Parse("003"));
```

See [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: But this will result in the formatting being lost, so parsing back is not really an option here.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an int object, the leading zeros will always be removed, regardless if you convert it to a string and back.

Answer (score 1):

use the pad function`int i = 1;
            i.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');`